# How to change a maximum file size limit with php

Tags: php, apache, unix, webserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

I use a free Web hosting service (Apache/2.2.17) on UNIX, I think . I use a php script to append data to some file in my home dir, with such code:

```
$my_handle = fopen($my_file_name, 'ab');
$bytes = fwrite($my_handle, $my_data);
fclose($my_handle);
```

When the file size reaches 128 MB, the script terminates, but no error is produced. So, I have to save data in 128 MB parts. Is there any way that I can change this "128 MB file size limit"?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure, there's no error? Maybe error reporting is turned off? Check *error_reporting* and *display_errors* directives.

Comment: Show us how your filling `$my_data`

Comment: Hi, Crozin! Thanks for the help! Usually I am getting a lot of errors when my scripts run before I debug them. I am not very experienced in php. But this error is not reported. The script just terminates and I end up with 128 MB file.

Comment: Hi, Vulcan. My question is not about upload file size limit, but about file system max file size limit, so, it does not seem to be a duplicate. The upload limit of my provider is 8 MB.

Comment: BTW, I checked the error_log file. There are errors there, but none of them pertaining the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the configuration in the PHP settings but you won't have that option available on free hosting. 
Upgrade your hosting.

Comment: Hi, Chris Vickery! Thanks for the help. Could you please elaborate which setting exactly has to be changed? The service provider says that I "can change most of PHP settings yourself by using php_flag values in .htaccess file and ini_set(), ini_alter() PHP functions".

Comment: @GreenBear Refer to the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size).

Comment: Vulcan, my question is not about upload limit. The upload limit of my provider is 8 MB.